How can I handle null in this situation: CustomerUSTempBuffer.vehiclereturndate = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(973, 8).Trim());?
I have a SSIS script component that reads a file. Multiple columns are DateTime. How do I handle when the line is null?
CustomerUSTempBuffer.vehiclereturndate = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(973, 8).Trim());
Thank you
I have searched and searched and cannot find an example that is close to this.

Do a null check first, then if null dont assign the value or try to parse it.
